# How to store coredata entity object into NSManageobject Class in core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an class of core data entity like this,

```
@interface Answer : SMManagedObject

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *expiresAt;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) StudentAssessments * assessment;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) Question * question;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) Assignment * assignment;

@end
```

I want to store object of StudentAssessments into Answer object class. So how can i do this?

Its raising error where i do that code for storing like,

```
 [newObjOfAnswer setAssessment:(StudentAssessments *)self.contentObject];
```

Here self.contentobject is as StudentAsssessments class.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Make sure the property is a relationship and not some sort of transient attribute.

Comment: yes i defined its as a relationship with entity.

Comment: You still haven't said **what error you are getting**. That's crucial information.